# Wondering which FAQ guideline this question violates?

Tags: discussion

I asked the following question recently:
[Small case for mac book air that will hold charger and mouse?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66192/small-case-for-mac-book-air-that-will-hold-charger-and-mouse#comment78237_66192)

and was curious why it was closed.

One person mentioned that he considered it a shopping question and that's why he thought it was shut down.  I had assumed since I wasn't asking for a place to buy a product or where I can find good prices, that this would not be considered a shopping question, but maybe I'm wrong.

Are questions about whether there exists equipment that meets specific requirements not appropriate for the Apple SE site? Any guidance for future questions welcome.

Comment: Thank you very much for asking this - several people have asked questions similar to yours and it will be very good to discuss things here as to why and what this site means by "no shopping questions".

Answer (score 2):

From [the FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq), emphasis added:

> Ask Different is for Apple enthusiasts and power users
>
> - Apple hardware
> - Apple software
> - other Apple products or services
> - third-party hardware
>     and software for Apple products
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!
>
> However, a few exceptions to the general scope exist.    Please
>   refrain from asking about...
>
> - Apple Developer Programs or iTunes Connect (including iAd and the iBookstore)
> - programming, with the exception of
>     AppleScript and Automator
> - installing or using Apple
>     operating systems on non-Apple hardware
> - ***a shopping or
>     buying recommendation for hardware or accessories like bags and
>     cases***
> - pre-release or beta software (We consider versions
>     not available to the public to be in this category)
> - obtaining or using pirated software or media

Comment: I want to point out that I [added the text ***or accessories like bags and cases*** to the FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/5788/revisions) after Abe's question was originally asked. Several people have asked quite reasonable questions about accessories so I wanted to clarify what a shopping question was.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I've seen that line. I guess I'm asking for clarification on what the difference is between a "shopping or buying recommendation" and a question about whether something exists.